# day differences using Calendar in java

Tags: android, date

I am using Calendar Class in my android app to calulate day of year of a date and then do some comparison with current day of year. Here is the code I use :

```
Date now=new Date();
Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ca1.set(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
        int nowC=ca1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

//Date arg0=say,get from user
        Calendar ca2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ca2.set(arg0.GetBirthDay().getYear(),arg0.GetBirthDay().getMonth(),arg0.GetBirthDay().getDate());
        int d1C=ca2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

I debug my application and I see the following value for current day : 
Fri Mar 02 14:18:33 Asia/Tehran 2012

and for arg0:
Fri Mar 02 00:00:00 Asia/Tehran 1979

And 'nowC' got 62, and 'd1C' got 61.

I expect them to be equal cause both of them has same month and day, also If I use DateTime class of joda package, as below, I get the same results:

```
int ndy=dtnow.getDayOfYear();
int d1dy=dt1.getDayOfYear();
```

Why it is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2012 was a leap year, 1979 was not. There is an extra day before March 2nd this year - so both APIs are giving you the right answer!

I suspect you want to compare both the month and day-of-month, to get the semantics you are expecting.

Comment: Exactly I want to compare someone`s birthday date from current date, and as you know the month and day of birthday are more important that its year